# How can i pass pathname and query in Next js 13.4 to router.push() in App router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My instructor using Next js 11 version, he used to `import router from "next/router"`. but as we know that `next/router` has been depreciated. he passes pathname and query to the `router.push` like this:

```
 router.push({
      pathname: path,
      query: query,
    });
```

How can i do it in App router? any suggestions?

I done a lot of work like manually forcing the link like this:

```
let search= searchParams.get("search")
....
if (search === null) {
      search = "";
    }
    if (brand === null) {
      brand = "";
    }
    if (categoryQuery === null) {
      categoryQuery = "";
    }
    if (pattern === null) {
      pattern = "";
    }
    if (size === null) {
      size = "";
    }
    if (gender === null) {
      gender = "";
    }
    if (color === null) {
      color = "";
    }

    if (material === null) {
      material = "";
    }

    router.push(
      `?style=${result}&search=${search}&size=${size}&color=${color}&pattern=${pattern}&gender=${gender}&material=${material}&category=${categoryQuery}&brand=${brand}`
    );
```

Yes, it's look ugly. and that's why i'm here. this is really not a good approach that defining every searchParam and it disturbs my filtering function which i was implementing right now for my next js. I want that cool approach back which was depreciated. **Please ignore if this question is stupid.**

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47583#discussioncomment-5449707